# Detect Country of IP address using AWS EC2 and cloudFront only on certain pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently using AWS EC2 to server my website. The content of the website is dynamic and most of the visitors are coming from specific number of countries.

I'm trying to detect the country of website visitors through their IP addresses. This needs to be performed only when visitors reach a specific page on my website (https://example.com/abc).

I know that AWS Cloudfront offers exactly what I need through the `CloudFront-Viewer-Country` header. However, I do not intend to serve the whole website behind CloundFront. I think my problem would be solved if there is a way to serve only a single page (https://example.com/abc) through CloudFront. Is this possible to achieve ? If so, how ?

What other options do I have ?

Comment: No, you can't serve just one page with CloudFront - it's dependent on DNS records. You could serve a subdomain with CloudFront... but why *wouldn't* you serve the entire website through CloudFront?

Comment: Reason is simple: cost saving, since most of the website content is dynamic. I'm already using CloudFront for serving static content of my website.

Comment: In that case, consider a GeoIP solution (which is what CloudFront is doing for you).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a pixel image of your cloudfront endpoint on your domain pages. Everytime user visits, your referred pixel will be called with the http referrer. (tells you which page is being called)

https://skillcrush.com/2012/07/19/tracking-pixel/

Alternatively you can add analytics tools like Google Analytics will capture lot more information for you about the visitors.